# First key from Language properties file not accessible

Tags: java, resourcebundle, properties-file

I have a language properties file with around 3000+ keys. When I try to read the value of a key using 
`ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.mt.asm.language.MessagesBundle", locale);`, I see that the first `key` alone is missing in the `messages` bundle.

I try to retrieve the value using: 
`String value = new String(messages.getString(key).getBytes("ISO-8859-1") , "UTF-8");`

I tried a lot to identify the root cause, but my tries were of no use.
**What could be the possible reason for this strange behaviour.**

Comment: Please see if first key is not overriden by assigning different value to this key somewhere below

Comment: Have you tried to delete all the keys but the first (or any other) and see what happend?

Comment: There are no duplicates for the first key. Even if I keep only 1 key, that doesn't get loaded in the bundle.

Comment: If replicate the first key you can get it? I mean 
       key1=value1 key1=value1 key2=value2

Comment: yes. that works. only the first key is not retrievable.

Comment: Well then the low-tech solution is: Add a comment or a dummy key at the first line of your properties file ;D

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the cause of the problem.

The `properties file` was in `UTF-8 BOM` format which was expecting `Byte Order Mark` in the file. This has been solved by using a `properties file` in `UTF-8` format.